# Finding date in a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings with different values, and im trying to find the strings in the list that are dates and return the index of the date. I tried using the dateutil parser like this:

```
x = ["test", "Hello", "abc", "27.02.2020"]
for item in x:
    if parse(item) == True:
        print(x.index(item))
```

This does not work since most of the strings in my list are not dates, and the parser does not recognize the format of the strings not being dates. Anyone got a solution to how i could solve this differently?

Comment: You can use regex to identify the dates that are strings.

Comment: My actual list has several items being integers and floats etc. So it would have to recognize a date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, the easiest one would be use `pandas.to_datetime()` which raise exception (ParserError) if not date

```py
import pandas as pd #pip install pandas


def is_date(date_string):
    try:
        pd.to_datetime(date_string, format='%d.%m.%Y')
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False
    
x = ["test", "Hello", "abc", "27.02.2020"]
for index, item in enumerate(x):
    if is_date(item):
        print(index)
```

Comment: This worked nicely. However, my list also contains timestamps such as "08:14:35", and those also get printed with this solution. Is there any way to only find the dates with %dd.%mm.%yyyy formats?

Comment: sure use the format `format='%d.%m.%Y'`. Check out the formats available here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use regular expression

```py
import re

x = ["test", "Hello", "abc", "27.02.2020"]
for item in x:
    if re.match(r'[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}', item):
        print(item, 'is a date')
```

Note that it cannot validate the dates, such as knowing `32nd of December` is not a valid date

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches for this, including the one proposed above - pattern matching.
If all the dates in your array have the same format, you could write a helper function which tries to parse the date given a format and, if a `ValueError` is thrown because it is not a date, returns `None` or whatever you prefer:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def try_parse(x, date_format="%d.%m.%Y"):
    try:
        return dt.strptime(x, date_format)
    except ValueError:
        return None

lst = ["test", "Hello", "abc", "27.02.2020"]

[try_parse(x) for x in lst]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 27, 0, 0)]
```

The advantage of this is that the only needed library is `datetime`. In addition, you could make it more robust passing a list of possible expected date formats and try to parse for all of them - so you are not limited to just your `%d.%m.%Y` - defaulting to something is no parsing is successful as in the solution above.

Anyway, I think this is what essentially `pandas.to_datetime` does, so you could simply do:

```
import pandas as pd

[pd.to_datetime(y, errors="coerce") for y in x]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[NaT, NaT, NaT, Timestamp('2020-02-27 00:00:00')]
```

The `errors=coerce` option makes the method return `NaT` in case parsing fails.